# Which formula of tf-idf does the LSA model of gensim use?

Tags: gensim, tf-idf, latent-semantic-indexing, latent-semantic-analysis

There are many different ways in which tf and idf can be calculated. I want to know which formula is used by gensim in its LSA model. I have been going through its source code `lsimodel.py`, but it is not obvious to me where the document-term matrix is created (probably because of memory optimizations).

In [one LSA paper](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~reidy.16/LSAtutorial.pdf), I read that each cell of the document-term matrix is the log-frequency of that word in that document, divided by the entropy of that word:

```
tf(w, d) = log(1 + frequency(w, d))
idf(w, D) = 1 / (-Σ_D p(w) log p(w))
```

However, this seems to be a very unusual formulation of tf-idf. A more familiar form of tf-idf is:

```
tf(w, d) = frequency(w, d)
idf(w, D) = log(|D| / |{d ∈ D: w ∈ d}|)
```

I also notice that there is a [question on how the `TfIdfModel` itself is implemented in gensim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470479/how-is-tf-idf-implemented-in-gensim-tool-in-python). However, I didn't see `lsimodel.py` importing `TfIdfModel`, and therefore can only assume that `lsimodel.py` has its own implementation of tf-idf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, `lsimodel.py` does not preform the tf-idf encoding step. You may find some details in gensim's [API documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html) - there's a dedicated tf-idf model, which can be employed to encode a text that can be later fed into the LSA model. From the `tfidfmodel.py` [source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/b6234e7d90ffe9aeda7fab4b39c484381d7c5930/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.py#L52) it appears that the latter of two definitions of tf-idf you listed is followed.